# Unable to validate number in React with Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am trying to validate an HTML-Input field rendered with React to only accept numbers. My current attempt to do that.

What must be done in order to validate the Input field to only accept numbers?

```js
phone: {
    elementLabel: 'Phone Number',
    elementType: 'input',
    elementConfig: {
        type: "number",
        placeholder: 'Phone Number',
        name: "phone",
        id: "phone",
        min: "0",
        pattern: "[0-9]*",
    },
    value: '',
    form_value: "",
    validation: {},
    valid: false,
    touched: false,
    className: "form-control",
    changed: (event) => this.inputChangedHandler(event,
    "phone"),
    blured: (event) => this.inputBlurHandler(event,
    "phone")
},
```

```
render(){
<div>
<Input {...this.state.name}/>
</div>
}
```

```
inputChangedHandler = (event, inputIdentifier) => {
        const updatedForm = {
            ...this.state
        };
        const updatedFormElement = {
            ...this.state[inputIdentifier]
        };
        Utils.updateElementValue(updatedFormElement, event, inputIdentifier);
        updatedFormElement.touched = true;
        updatedForm[inputIdentifier] = updatedFormElement;

        let formIsValid = true;
        for (let inputIdentifier in updatedForm) {
            if (updatedForm[inputIdentifier].elementType) {
                formIsValid = updatedForm[inputIdentifier].valid && formIsValid;
            }
        }
        this.setState({ [inputIdentifier]: updatedFormElement, formIsValid: formIsValid });
    }
```

Also this is my change handler looks like
Number is not validated when taking input from the control. While using this, I want validaiton that only input numbers, not even any special characters.

**Edit 1:**

I use the following versions:

- bootstrap: ^4.3.1
- react: ^16.8.6

Comment: try using like this pattern: ".{10}", let me know if it worked for you

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS Didn;t work

Comment: @Nandani Please add the versions of React and Bootstrap to your post. Also, add more context of where you use `phone` exactly. A JSON is not enough. Show us what variable you put it in and where you make use of it.

Comment: "bootstrap": "^4.3.1" , "react": "^16.8.6"
 @Socrates Also updated question with render

Answer (score 0):

I think the pattern you are using is wrong. It should be `^[0-9]*$` which accepts any number of digits, including none.

Comment: Can you post the definition of `inputChangedHandler` function for `phone` attribute?

Comment: Updated question with handler

Comment: Where's the call for validation function using the pattern?

Comment: I don't have any

Comment: If you don't use the pattern for validation of input at all, how do you validate it?

Comment: I've kept type number but still able to put characters

Comment: Clearly, it's not working here. I believe it's because your `input` element is of type `text` and not `number`. It should look something like `<input type="number" name="blah" min="1" max="5">`. Please check it using inspect elements functionality.

Comment: How to restrict text to alphabets only?

Comment: Did you check what I suggested in my last comment?